# SQL update statement for a list of fixed value

Tags: sql

I have a list of key/value pairs which I would like to update via a single SQL statement. The update value is different for each row. it seems fairly trivia to do a dynamic update using values from another table. But I don't have the update to values in a table, and I would prefer not to create a temp table to do so.

I would like to be able to do something like

```
UPDATE table
SET update_column = IN(value1,value2)
WHERE key_column IN(Key1 , Key2)
AND Criteria_column = 'Criteria'
```

Comment: How about using a CASE/IIF stateemnt (depending on which RDBMS you are using)?

Comment: Where are your key value pairs stored?

Comment: I have a list exported into excel from an erp applicaton

Answer (score 1):

In PostgreSQL, and probably in other databases, you can (somewhat clumsily) build up a "table" in-place using `UNION ALL`:

```
UPDATE table
SET update_column = temp.value
FROM (
    SELECT 'foo' AS id, 'bar' AS value
      UNION ALL
    SELECT 'baz' AS id, 'qux' AS value
      UNION ALL
    SELECT 'et' AS id, 'cetera' AS value
) temp
WHERE key_column = temp.id
AND Criteria_column = 'Criteria';
```

In more recent versions of PostgreSQL, the syntax for building an in-place table has been improved:

```
UPDATE table
SET update_column = temp.value
FROM (
    VALUES ('foo', 'bar'), ('baz', 'qux'), ('et', 'cetera')
) temp (id, value)
WHERE key_column = temp.id
AND Criteria_column = 'Criteria';
```

Comment: thanks for that, I should have said I am using oracle.... this syntax doesn't seem to work for oracle.

Comment: @Pynner: I see. Are you able to concatenate queries together using `UNION` or `UNION ALL`? I *think* that's standard SQL... If not, there might be a different syntax for it in Oracle. Also it might be that you just need to add `AS` before the table name `temp`. But it might be that allowing `FROM` in an `UPDATE` is a PostgreSQL extension... in that case, there must be some other syntax for pulling in other tables (e.g. using a subselect, e.g. `SET update_column = (SELECT ...)`), because I can't believe Oracle forbids any kind of table join in an `UPDATE` -- it would be too limiting.